# Automatically refresh a query in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a way to automatically refresh the result of a query in the SQL Server Management Studio (SQL Server 2008 R2)?

Currently I'm debugging an application which automatically inserts and updates data in a database and I'd like to track the progress without having to deposit a heavy object on the F5 key.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT GETDATE()              --your query to run
raiserror('',0,1) with nowait --to flush the buffer
waitfor delay '00:00:10'      --pause for 10 seconds
GO 5                          --loop 5 times
```

It will run the query 5 times, pausing for 10 seconds between each run

Output:

```
Beginning execution loop

-----------------------
2011-03-25 11:03:57.640
(1 row(s) affected)

-----------------------
2011-03-25 11:04:07.640
(1 row(s) affected)

-----------------------
2011-03-25 11:04:17.640
(1 row(s) affected)

-----------------------
2011-03-25 11:04:27.640
(1 row(s) affected)

-----------------------
2011-03-25 11:04:37.640
(1 row(s) affected)

Batch execution completed 5 times.
```

Comment: @RacerX - What if you want it run it every 10 seconds, without upper limit of 5?

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag, you need a `count` so it loops, see [GO (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx). The `count` is an int, so it can be quite large: 2,147,483,647. So just use `GO 2147483647`

Comment: But you need to flush the buffer. Add `raiserror('',0,1) with nowait` before the `waitfor`.

Comment: @Martin, that works like a charm, I've edited my answer to include that

Comment: +1 It only seemed to affect the first execution so not sure if it is automatically flushed at the end of each batch.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to refresh the one result set instead having it create one result set for each iteration?

Comment: @wergeld: set the result pane to return results as text, not grid. (not sure how the english menu is labeled, but in my client you can do it with CTRL+T)

Comment: @RacerX: I didn't know you could do that with a GO statement. Nice solution. GO 30000 keeps me going for the whole day.

Comment: ...ok GO 30000 wasn't such a great idea after all, my ssms crashed during my lunch break when it ran out of memory. ;-)

Comment: @grimmig That does display the result 5 times but still with 5 result sets (just not in window form). I meant to say, is there a way to loop the query using this method and have it "re-draw" the results such that I only have one total output?

Comment: I don't know.

For my application it's enough to resize the output so it only shows the last 5 rows where the interesting stuff is happening.

Comment: @wergeld: quick&dirty fix: add 10 times `PRINT ''` before the query  to scroll the old values out of the window

Comment: @grimmig: Unfortunately, text display seems to display only the first requested column.

Comment: Instead of a bunch of `PRINT ''`, you can do a single `PRINT REPLICATE(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), 50)`

Answer (score 8):

The only thing I can think of that would do that enitrely from SSMS would be a loop with a [WAITFOR](http://shannonlowder.com/2008/09/flow-control/) option.  The problem is your output query window will simply have multiple result sets, each one later in your process than the one before it.

In this situation I usually suggest building a simple web page that runs from locally on your machine.  Build it to take a query, and set it to auto-refresh every *interval* (30-60-90 seconds).

But that would be outside SSMS.

Comment: +1 That is a good point actually. I seem to remember there might be a 100 resultset limit or something like that. (Edit: Maybe that was 2005 I saw that in.)

Comment: I've run the same setup as in my answer for many many result sets without problem.  I do run in text mode, and the only problem is copy/paste memory limits.  If I expect large result sets, I run the output to a file, you can edit it as it grows to get see what is going on in it.

Comment: WAITFOR in a loop is a nice suggestion, but using "GO 1000" requries less lines cluttering my SQL query.

(also making a webpage would be overkill for this case)