# Can you view the contents of a SQL (Server) table in realtime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, real-time

Is it possible to have a table or view which updates in real-time - so I can see the changes without refreshing?

The nearest thing I ever found was

```
raiserror('',0,1) with nowait --to flush the buffer
print 'hello'                 --say hello
waitfor delay '00:00:01'      --pause for 1 second
GO 5                          --loop 5 times
```

but obviously using that for a select gives you multiple tables rather than refreshing the table

Comment: It's not a common requirement, and could impose a heavy load on the server to support such viewing - so there's nothing built in.

Comment: for my requirements, I am fine with it being a hack, and even one refresh per second would be sufficient. Even a sql-server only solution would do for me.

Comment: Did you base your question off [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434192/automatically-refresh-a-query-in-ms-sql-server-management-studio "Automatically refresh a query in ms sql server management studio?")?

Comment: That was the nearest thing I ever found. Is there some way to embed code from a code wiki, I vaguely remember something like that in other things I have seen on this site.

Answer (score 1):

[Query Notifications](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) can update you in real time when changes in the table occur, but you will have to query again the table to see *what* changed. At the least it eliminates pooling. As a cache-invalidation solution, is intended to be used with relatively static data that changes seldom.

For frequent changing data the best is to poll and have a way to return only the changes (eg. `updated_at`) but is rather trickier to detect *deletes*.

[Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is a technology that will record changes (and makes discovery of deletes trivial) and you can query for the changes, but is intended for occasionally connected systems (eg. Phones updating the local snapshot from the mothership database), not for live change monitoring.

Comment: I spent a while reading that, and it is quite interesting, but what I am essentially wanting is a SELECT * FROM table, which will _refresh_ either on an event, or even simpler, after a short interval - within the SQL Server Management Studio query interface.