# Is it possible to execute a SQL dbo automatically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Sorry if I sound ignorant but I'm new to SQL. I'm using SQL Server 2008. Basically I have a dbo object that displays a list of items, and when I hit "execute" the list refreshes with the most current data.

My question is this: is there a way to set this to execute automatically every minute or so while the table display is open? I plan on sharing out the view of the database so that people can see how far along the DB is before attempting to query it.

Hopefully that makes sense. I tried Google'ing but this seems like a rather vague topic or I'm just too confused to understand what some of these sites are saying. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Clarification:
By "dbo object" I meant a table (I think?). For example it's named dbo.Bridge, and when I right click it I click "edit top 200 rows" to see the data, and then I click the red exclamation mark at the top of SQL Server 2008 to "Execute", which causes the table to update

Comment: By "hit execute" do you mean in SSMS?

Comment: What does "a dbo object" mean?

Comment: Sorry guys. By "dbo object" I meant a table (I think?). For example it's named dbo.Bridge, and when I right click it I click "edit top 200 rows" to see the data, and then I click the red exclamation mark at the top of SQL Server 2008 to "Execute", which causes the table to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in SQL Server Management Studio or Visual Studio SQL Server Explorer then you won't be able to do it. You can set delays to execute, however:

```
WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select * from [test_p]
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'
END
```

This will keep appending onto the existing results, however, that is just a limitation of the software. It isn't meant to do things like this. You're better off just writing a simple script or view to execute every so often and display the data in some other way.

Comment: When you say "simple script", how would you suggest I go about that? Specifically in what language?

Comment: There are ways to access SQL databases every major language out there. If you're familiar with Python then that would be the simplest language (in terms of syntax) to do it. It really depends how much you're trying to display and in what format.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `waitfor`, something like:

```
waitfor delay '000:01:00'
select * from MyTable
go 30
```

This will run the select 30 times, waiting a minute between each run.
(borrowed from [Automatically refresh a query in ms sql server management studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434192/automatically-refresh-a-query-in-ms-sql-server-management-studio)).

Another option would be to drop the query into a connection in an excel spreadsheet (for example), and set the background refresh options (workbook connections --> properties).  This is most likely easier than keeping something running all day in sql server.

Edit: If `GO` does not work for you, check in options to see what word/character is set as your Batch Separator and replace `GO` with that word.

Comment: The "go 30" doesn't work for me, otherwise this is a good semi-solution. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped - sorry the `go` didn't work for you.  I tested in SQL 2014 - will try again when I am back at that computer.  Documentation is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @Brady, I believe the problem with `GO` is related to your locally-set batch separator, and have edited the answer to add that.

Comment: Note, though, that I still think the easiest option would be to use Excel's timed refresh options and distribute that spreadsheet to your users.  See http://superuser.com/questions/254526/how-can-i-make-excel-fetch-data-from-a-database-automatically-when-i-open-the-sp to get started.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link.