# Microsoft SQL Server auto refresh

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I saw this: [Automatically refresh a query in SQL Server Management Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434192/automatically-refresh-a-query-in-ms-sql-server-management-studio/5434294#5434294)

The resolution suggested was:

```
SELECT GETDATE()              --your query to run
raiserror('',0,1) with nowait --to flush the buffer
waitfor delay '00:00:10'      --pause for 10 seconds
GO 5
```

Can I use that to check if my sever connection is breaking over the day? I'm having this issue at work and would like to run this every 30 minutes to see if at some point the server won't connect, will it stop running if the server fails once? how can I know what time the server failed? Thanks!

Comment: If you have those sort of issues there are many tools available to detect, troubleshoot and alert which you definitely should have in a production environment eg [r-u-on](https://www.r-u-on.com/)

Comment: or create a simple python script or use a familiar programming language to cover that or send you an email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you attached is a way to periodically execute a query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and refresh the results since it will execute the query and then pause for 10 seconds before executing it again. The `GO 5` statement at the end indicates that the code block should be executed five times. If the server fails to connect or encounters an error during any of those iterations, the code will not automatically stop running. Instead, it will continue executing until all five iterations are completed.

You can use dedicated monitoring tools like Nagios, Zabbix, or Datadog where you can use comprehensive monitoring capabilities, including server availability checks and alerting when connections fail.

If you are familiar with PowerShell you can write a script that periodically connects to the server and logs the results. This script can be scheduled to run every 30 minutes using the Windows Task Scheduler. If the connection fails, the script can write a log entry with the timestamp indicating the time of the failure.

Also you can use SQL Server Agent Jobs to schedule and monitor your queries and send email notifications or write entries to the Windows Event Log when there are failures.